# Can I send event and a param to a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my code :

```
export default class HeroDetail extends Component {
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
 }

 updateHeroName(event) {
     this.props.actions.changeName(this.props.heroAppState.selectedHero.id, event.target.value);
 }
 render() {
   const _hero = this.props.heroAppState.selectedHero;
     return (
           <div>
             <input placeholder="name"
               value={_hero.name}
               onChange={this.updateHeroName.bind(this)} />
            </div>             
     );
   }
 }
```

I want to bind `updateHeroName`  at the top. And pass 2 param(hero_id and event) into `updateHeroName`  But I don't know how to pass event and a param named `_hero.id`  , So the code not work. Can I do this in javascript??

```
// Fail code 
export default class HeroDetail extends Component {
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.updateHeroName = this.updateHeroName.bind(this);
 }

 updateHeroName(hero_id, event) {
     this.props.actions.changeName(hero_id, event.target.value);
 }
 render() {
   const _hero = this.props.heroAppState.selectedHero;
     return (
           <div>
             <input placeholder="name"
               value={_hero.name}
               onChange={this.updateHeroName(_hero.id, event)} />
            </div>             
     );
   }
 }
```

Comment: You can do it like this `onChange={ (event) => this.updateHeroName(_hero.id, event) }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
export default class HeroDetail extends Component {
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.updateHeroName = this.updateHeroName.bind(this);
 }

 updateHeroName(hero_id, event) {
     this.props.actions.changeName(hero_id, event.target.value);
 }
 render() {
   const _hero = this.props.heroAppState.selectedHero;
     return (
           <div>
             <input placeholder="name"
               value={_hero.name}
               onChange={(event) => this.updateHeroName(_hero.id, event)} />
            </div>             
     );
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like `onChange={ (event) => this.updateHeroName(‌​_hero.id, event) }` (as [Alexander T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367138/alexander-t) suggested)

But generally, it's better not to use arrow functions or `bind` methods inside `render` as it generates a new copy of the function on any `render` call. Move function declaration to the `class constructor`.

I personally prefer to use arrow functions as class properties in this case

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {

  handleClick = () => {
    // your logic
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</button>
    );
  }
}
```

It's not a part of ES2015 specification but [babel stage-0 preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/) supports this syntax

You can read more about context binding in React in [this article](http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html)